# How do you pass parameters from Laravel into a stand alone HTML file?

Tags: html, laravel

How do you go about passing parameters from a controller in laravel to a stand alone HTML file. Note that this file is not included in the Laravel project and is a pure HTML file.

The controller is as so;

```
public function sendWarranty($data)
{
   // code here.
}
```

The parameters that I want to pass over to the HTML file are from the `$data` array. There are value such as customer name, customer phone number, invoice number and so on in this array which I would need to access in the HTML file. 
Is that do-able?

Basically, my laravel project right now is in a url, say www.xxx-cms.com ; the html is in another url, say www.xxx-warranty.com

Comment: you want the variables from a controller be passed on a static html file that is outside of the project and with different url? as far as i know, controller can only pass value to a blade file, which is a php page. also, please read about XSS attack.

Comment: hey @kapitan thanks for the heads up. however i'm not worried about the xss attack as the site is protected by auth tokens and is only accessible if the user gets an sms. Also yeah, clients require us to put the website outside of the laravel project, which is why it's a pain

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to load the file through GuzzleHttp into a variable and do some string replace and then return the variable as the response

```
public function sendWarranty($data)
{
   $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
   $res = $client->get('https://www.xxx-warranty.com')->getBody();
   //some string replacements
   $res= str_replace('$BRANDNAME$',$data['brand_name'],$res);
   return $res;
}
```

By the way you can send params to www.xxx-warranty.com using this:

```
   $res = $client->get('https://www.xxx-warranty.com',['param'=>'value',])->getBody();
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! got a question though, how do i call the params in html then? say in my html i have an input like such `<input class="form-control" type="text" id="brand" name="brand" value="{{!! $battery['brand_name'] !!}}" readonly>` do i call the value as such? in the params at the controller i have already defined it as such `['brand' => $battery['brand_name']]`

Comment: Unfortunately, if it was HTML not blade you have to treat them as a string and replace it using str_replace('$BRANDNAME$',$brand_name,$res);

Comment: ohh, but where do i do this? in the controller or at the html itself?

Comment: oh sweet, what about the html part? so my `<input type="text id="brand" value="?">`
do i need to make any changes here?

Comment: value="$BRANDNAME$"

Comment: sweet! let me try it out!

Comment: i just saw GuzzleHttp's documentation, thanks for the heads-up, im not aware on this. upvoted!